# Can there be a use case diagram for an app that is completely offline?

Tags: uml, client-side, use-case-diagram

I am building an app that is completely client side with 0 backend, as all the data is completely static and non modifiable. From what I understand of USE case diagrams, they are supposed to represent actions and reactions between user and server. But if there is no involvement of a server, can there be a USE case diagram??

I tried looking up on reddit and stack overflow but didn't find anything on specifically on client side apps. I am expecting an explanation.

Comment: If a system is completely autonomous and does not interact it's useless to anyone (except for its own purpose). An eremite would be the only such thing. But any other system has something it will be useful for.

Comment: Where did you get "user and server" from? Use cases are usually in the form of a conversation between user and **system**. Cient/Server are components of such a system, but the system as a whole is viewed as a black box in use case modelling.

Comment: Geert, I got that from a Bank app example the tutorial person was explaining. But then again even as a system, the app I am working on doesnt Exactly React as a whole. Its mostly "Click button, visuals happen". I dont know how I would go about making a USE case diagram for such App.

Comment: qwerty_so, Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I did end up making a sequence diagram. Which was easy enough to make as the app does have a flow. A use case was just not making sense in my head.

Comment: Use cases are not about buttons and visuals, but about what the main goals of a user are when using the software. What are they trying to achieve in a way that it yields an observable (useful) result? It's definitely not pressing buttons or seeing visuals happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a use-case as long as you have an actor, a subject (i.e. a system), and a goal.  According to the UML specifications:

> Each UseCase specifies some behavior that a ***subject*** can perform in collaboration with one or more ***Actors***. UseCases define the offered Behaviors of the subject **without reference to its internal structure**.

Front-end, backend, client-side app, server are about internal structure of your system.  They don't matter for the use-case.  What matters is the goal that an actor (user) wants to achieve with your system.

Use-cases are not either meant to describe the details of the interaction with your system.  Modeling such details requires somehow to take into account the sequence of the interactions or the flow of events.  Use-cases, on contrary, have no sequential order and no workflow.  There are other modeling for that.

Last but not least,  use-cases shall not to be confused with user-interfaces. User interface is about how the interaction happen, whereas use-case is what the interaction is about.  Use wireframes or other techniques for user-interfaces.  Even the inventor of use-cases, Ivar Jacobson, explained that it was a bad thing to let user interface design be tied to use-cases.

Comment: Right, reading that definition. Does it imply that there can be a USE case diagram... Without a system? Because if I am to apply what you said with the app am working with. The app am working on doesn't exactly have a system so to speak of. Its a ThreeJS super fancy front end heavy portfolio website. Where there are no inputs or any form data processing going on. Aka there's no system. Or a very very basic system(If "click, thing happens" counts as a system).

Comment: The **system** under consideration is always explicit. Sometimes it's show as a boundary around the UC bubbles with the actor outside. Take the time to read Bittner/Spence about UCs.

Comment: @Sheru if there's a user, there's a system. It can be a simple front-end, or a complex distributed system. The fact that the user uses your app, show that the app  helps to achieve some goals. And here you have your use-cases, independently of the (light) internal structure and the user interface ;-)